# Alphavantage: Requests from different api keys but from the same system

Tags: python, alpha-vantage

I have written a python script that helps me get the prices from alphavantage using an api key. I have 2 different alphavantage api keys (mine and my brother's) and the python script requests data from alphavantage separately from both keys but from the same laptop. But even though I request it separately from separate keys, I get the maximum api call frequency exceeded error (5 api calls per minute per key).

My best assumption is that alphavantage knows whether the request is coming from the same location or the same system. Is there any workaround this problem? Maybe bounce my signal (sort of found an answer but don't know if that's the problem though!) or pretend like the request is going from different system?

Answer (score 1):

Your IP is limited to 5 requests per minute regardless of how many keys you cycle through, so you would need to cycle through that as well.

I went through the same issue and just ended up buying their premium key. It's well worth it. You can also alternatively add a time delay and just run the script in the background so it doesn't time out.

You can also try polygon API its 60 requests per minute for free
https://polygon.io/pricing

Comment: How much does it cost? they don't seem to publish their prices